# Power law distribution of Mixed Poisson random variable

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, mixing-variables

Let $X$ a positive random variable with power law distribution with exponent $\tau$, meaning that there exists $c>0$ such that its CDF has the form
\begin{equation}
1-F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\ge x)\sim cx^{-(\tau-1)}.
\end{equation}

Define the random variable $Y$ defined on $\mathbb{N}^+$to have mixed Poisson distribution with mixing distribution F
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\mathbb{E}(e^{-X}\frac{X^k}{k!}).
\end{equation}
How can one prove that $Y$ has power law distribution with the same exponent $\tau$?

I get stuck when substituting in the integral, since i get
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y\ge x)\approx\sum_{k\ge x}\frac{1}{k!}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}{y^k}cy^{-\tau}dy
\end{equation}
and I don't see how it should follow a power law

Comment: The  exact formula is $$\Pr(Y>k)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}\frac{u^k}{k!}(1-F(u))du.$$